# Why does my DataGridView refresh automatically when i call a function that executes a select query and returns a datatable object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

this is my function runQuery it's a member of a classe called Dconnection it returns a DataTable object:

```
public DataTable runQuery(string qry)
    {
        dt.Clear();
        cmd.CommandText = qry;
        con.Open();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        dt.Load(rdr);
        con.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

Here is the buttons code :

```
    Dconnection dcon = new Dconnection();
    DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
    private void btnFillDGV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtable = dcon.runQuery("select * from books");         
        DGV.DataSource = dtable;            
    }

    private void btnExecQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dcon.runQuery("select * from books where ID =1");

    }
```

When i click the first button the DataGridView gets filled:

The problem is when i click the second button the DGV is refreshed automatically , please can some body explain why that's happening

Answer (score 2):

Your `runQuery` method isn't creating a new `DataTable`; it reuses the same `DataTable` instance that is already defined as the source of the `DataGridView`. So when you clear and refill it, it refreshes the `DataGridView`.

To fix it, just instantiate a new `DataTable`:

```
public DataTable runQuery(string qry)
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    cmd.CommandText = qry;
    con.Open();
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    table.Load(rdr);
    con.Close();
    return table;
}
```

As a side note, you should avoid reusing `DbConnection`, `DbCommand` and `DbDataReader` objects; it's a recipe for trouble. Just create new ones when you need them, and dispose them when you're done (the easiest way is to declare them in a `using` block):

```
public DataTable runQuery(string qry)
{
    var table = new DataTable();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = qry;
        connection.Open();
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            table.Load(rdr);
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your DataGridView has a DataTable as it's DataSource and you are clearing and reloading the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are manipulating same `dt` in two buttons.

```
 DGV.DataSource = dtable;
```

Here you are setting your `dataSource` to `dtable` which is returning value from your function and that is your datatable `(dt)`. And in second button click you are Clearing your `dt` which is your dataSource,and your data grid view is refreshing.To prevent this define a new `DataTable` in your method:

```
public DataTable runQuery(string qry)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmd.CommandText = qry;
    con.Open();
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    dt.Load(rdr);
    con.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

Don't forget, classes are reference types,in this line:

```
dtable = dcon.runQuery("select * from books");
```

You are doing:

```
dtable = dt;
```

Therefore if you make some change in `dt`,it will affect your dtable which is your data source.